# How to get the range of rows based on Date in my Sql?

Tags: mysql

I'm New to My SQL, i have a table list of patients, Now i need to fetch the Patients based on Date, so i have column with `date_column`. But `date_column` in string format I'm unable to get the range of values between some Dates. this what i tried

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Patients 
 WHERE date_column >= '2018-01-01' 
   AND date_column <= '2019-01-01';
```

But the problem is my date string like this `Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2018` so getting result unexpected and wrong rows it is showing.

Even i tried with

`STR_TO_Date` to convert the string to date format but above date forma i didn't find.

SO please can anybody help me out

Comment: If you're interested in using an RDBMS then I would suggest that you fix  date_column, so that it isn't in string format.

Comment: Actually it is done by some body else and need to modify some part i came to the picture they taken date_column as var_char

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE('Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2018','GMT',''),'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y')x;
+---------------------+
| x                   |
+---------------------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

or

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2018','%a %b %d %H:%i:%s GMT %Y')x;
+---------------------+
| x                   |
+---------------------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

And now fix your schema!